# Retrieving ids of records in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to retrieve the ids of the item records in elasticsearch

here is how I'm retrieving my items

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/ca_dev/item/_search?pretty'
```

Sample output of one of the Elasticsearch records

```
{
    "_index" : "ca_dev",
    "_type" : "item",
    "_id" : "22d65d47-3f1c-4349-9727-3e7fdc9839ab",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "id" : "22d65d47-3f1c-4349-88e7-3e7fdc9837ee",
      "description" : "Bulk Item #32",
      "item_number" : "123ad",
      "brand_line_description" : null,
      "product_type_description" : null,
      "size_profile_description" : null,
      "sortable_name" : "Bulk item",
      "branches" : [ ],
      "districts" : [ ],
      "inventories" : [ ],
      "sort_codes" : [ ],
      "in_stock" : false,
      "long_description" : null,      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use source filter : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-source-filtering.html

```
{
    "_source": ["id"],
    "query": ...
}
```